# Unable to read frame from video for time value= 1089000 milli sec?

Tags: python, opencv

I have written this code which reads frame from video at a specific time.I have provided the data set below. I am able to read frames till 580843 ms. Above that I am getting a false value for 'ret'. Length of my video is 1154000 ms. ms= milliseconds. I will appreciate if someone is able to identify why is it happening like this & a solution for the same. 
Thanks in Advance!!!

data set      140033,191001,228283,245265,270808,286592,293878,310243,352469,375504,397433,410997,431035,439021,456558,469285,477976,489867,496843,513780,520805,528651,536385
580843,617097,630329,652290,660603,667891,676055,689438,734821,775232,789900,800481,811521,817390,824388,849925,866860,873889,908463,945620,952115,966052,973513,988208,1002409,1050239,1067801,1089931

```
import cv2             
import numpy as np 
frame_no
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('1.avi')
fps =cap.get(5)
frame_count=cap.get(7)
frame_no = 1089000
cap.set(0,frame_no);
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.imwrite("par1-" + ".jpg",frame)
print ret
print frame_no
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please be specific and detailed in your question. Is it happening for this specific file `1.avi` ? Also, format your question properly and remove unnecessary lines (e.g enter code here.)

Comment: Hi Ujjwal, It is same for others file as well. If I am crossing the  1000000 milli sec threshold. It's not reading the frame. I had checked by using the 'ret' value which in this case is false.

Comment: Maybe the length of video sequence is not long enough ?

Comment: Hi @ ZdaR , I have re framed my question. The length of the video is more than the extreme value of frame I am trying to extract. You can refer the dataset.